# Spring boot not a managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Quite new to spring and i'm having a hard time dealing with this error ! I looked up many simular problems and tried the proposed solutions (@EntityScan, @ComponentScan). I also tried moving all the files in one package as suggested in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug53epaPFrA) but once again nothing wrong ! I just can't find where is the mistake i made !

- the error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-11-29T15:54:30.869+01:00 ERROR 33472 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IEleveRepository' defined in fr.school.schoolmanagement.repo.IEleveRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class fr.school.schoolmanagement.model.Eleve
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at fr.school.schoolmanagement.SchoolApplication.main(SchoolApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class fr.school.schoolmanagement.model.Eleve
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

- Eleve.java file:

```
package fr.school.schoolmanagement.model;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity 
@Table(name="eleve")
public class Eleve {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="eleve_id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="eleve_nom")
    private String nom;
    
    @Column(name="eleve_prenom")
    private String prenom; 
    
    @Column(name="eleve_date")
    private Date dateDeNaissance;
    
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }
    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }
    public Date getDateDeNaissance() {
        return dateDeNaissance;
    }
    public void setDateDeNaissance(Date dateDeNaissance) {
        this.dateDeNaissance = dateDeNaissance;
    }   
}
```

- EleveRepository file:

```
package fr.school.schoolmanagement.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import fr.school.schoolmanagement.model.Eleve;

@Repository
public interface IEleveRepository extends JpaRepository<Eleve, Integer> {

}
```

- EleveService file:

```
package fr.school.schoolmanagement.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import fr.school.schoolmanagement.model.Eleve;
import fr.school.schoolmanagement.repo.IEleveRepository;

@Service
public class EleveService {
    
    @Autowired
    private IEleveRepository eleveRepo;
    
    public Eleve saveEleve(Eleve eleve) {
        return this.eleveRepo.save(eleve); 
    }

}
```

- Main Application file:

```
package fr.school.schoolmanagement;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"fr.school.schoolmanagement.model"})
public class SchoolApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchoolApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

- and my tree looks like this:
  [image]

Comment: No need to add `@ComponentScan({"fr.school.schoolmanagement.model"})`, remove it and try again.

Comment: Also, the annotation `@Table(name="eleve")` name there is redundant when the name of the model mathed the entity, no matter the case.

Comment: thank @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo just tried your suggestions, still not working

Comment: Judging from your stacktrace you are using SPring Boot 3. Judging from your entity you are messing around with your dependencies and included incompatible ones. The annotations should come from `jakarta.persistence` package **not** `javax.persistence`. EIther fix the annotations or downgrade Spring Boot to 2.7.5.

Comment: @M.Deinum, THANK YOU, you just saved me after so many hours of rewriting, reading the same docs, tutorial

Comment: Also thanks @M.Deinum - this does not seem to be documented anywhere

Comment: If you are using the proper dependency management you only get the jakarta packaging and you have no other option. If you are upgrading from Spring Boot 2.x to 3.x it is clearly mentioned in the upgrade guide.

Comment: @M.Deinum wasted around 6 hours. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a entityManagerFactory bean, you have to pay attention to the setPackagesToScan value which must correspond to the package that hosts your entity classes.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
emf.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
emf.setPackagesToScan("your.domain.package.entity.name");
...........
```