# How to fix the error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.data.MyObj?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, junit5, hsqldb, spring-boot-test

Have anyone got this issue resolved?
"Not a managed type".

Sounds quite a simple one, but annoying that it is already defined inside the scanning package hierarchy.

Details of what I'm trying to accomplish are as follows:

### Aim

I'm trying to get Unit Tests (JUnit5) for JPA running in my demo project. Here's the code:

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

com.example.demo.DemoApplication:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.example.demo")

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

com.example.demo.domain.MyObj:

```java
package com.example.demo.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyObj {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String message;
}
```

com.example.demo.domain.MyObjRepository:

```java
package com.example.demo.domain;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

//@Repository
public interface MyObjRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObj, Long> {
}
```

com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

### Issue

When the tests are run `mvn clean test` I get this error which stops the build/test:

```
[ERROR] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests.contextLoads -- Time elapsed: 0.004 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@16391278 testClass = com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.example.demo.DemoApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1b11171f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4b0d79fc, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1ed6388a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@55a147cc, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@129aca4d], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
.
.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myObjRepository' defined in com.example.demo.domain.MyObjRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.domain.MyObj
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775)
.
.


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.domain.MyObj
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82)
```

### What I did so far

I tried the following threads with no luck:

Spring-boot : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.smart.entities.User - Stack Overflow
[Spring-boot : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.smart.entities.User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716311/spring-boot-caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type)

hibernate - Error creating bean with name 'XXX: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'XXX' - Stack Overflow
[Error creating bean with name 'XXX: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'XXX'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408757/error-creating-bean-with-name-xxx-unsatisfied-dependency-expressed-through-fie)

Answer (score 0):

So -- the issue was that I was using `javax.persistence`.

Changed to `jakarta.persistence` and problem went away.

I quote form:

java - Spring boot not a managed type - Stack Overflow
[Spring boot not a managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616311/spring-boot-not-a-managed-type)

> "Judging from your stacktrace you are using SPring Boot 3. Judging
> from your entity you are messing around with your dependencies and
> included incompatible ones. The annotations should come from
> jakarta.persistence package not javax.persistence. EIther fix the
> annotations or downgrade Spring Boot to 2.7.5. –  M. Deinum  Nov 29,
> 2022 at 15:29"